# How to fix "something wicked happened" in Software Center?

Tags: software-center, software-sources

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04. Whenever I try to download a new app from the Ubuntu Software Center, it says:

> Requires unauthenticated packages

It then gives me an option to "Repair". When I click on "Repair", it starts "Updating cache" with the progress bar stuck at zero.

---

If I try download or install any package via terminal, it gets stuck at

> connecting to archive.ubuntu.com

and I end up with the

> something wicked happened...

error message.

I've tried changing the server from 'Software Sources' as mentioned in the troubleshooter. But that doesn't help and the problem persists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install a package due to "Something wicked happened resolving" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207849/cant-install-a-package-due-to-something-wicked-happened-resolving-error)

Answer (score 4):

Check all the repositories from software sources and then update the software catalog using update manager. Then retry again.

If it doesn't work, try the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get -f
```

And include the output of this command in the question.

Comment: I would also include a sudo apt-get update.