# "Something wicked happened" error in apt-get

Tags: 13.04, apt, updates

Everytime I try to install through terminal I get this" 
I am not able to install or update and I can't find working answer for this here.
Here is my apt-get update result:

```
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg                                
Hit http://deb.opera.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg                                
Hit http://deb.opera.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release                                    
Hit http://deb.opera.com stable/non-free i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages                         
Ign http://deb.opera.com stable/non-free Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://deb.opera.com stable/non-free Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en                        
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg                               
  Something wicked happened resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-11 - System error)
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg                                
  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-11 - System error)
Err http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
  Something wicked happened resolving 'dl.google.com:http' (-11 - System error)
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg           
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release.gpg                       
  Something wicked happened resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-11 - System error)
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security Release.gpg [933 B]            
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed Release.gpg [933 B]            
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports Release.gpg [933 B]           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring Release                                   
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release [40.8 kB]    
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security Release [40.8 kB]              
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com raring Release                                    
Ign http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release                
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed Release [40.8 kB]              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports Release                         
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources/DiffIndex                    
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Sources/DiffIndex              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Sources/DiffIndex                
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex   
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex          
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en                 
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en                   
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Sources/DiffIndex            
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Sources/DiffIndex      
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Sources/DiffIndex        
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex     
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex      
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex      
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex  
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Translation-en         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Translation-en         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en           
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Sources [24.7 kB]         
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Sources [14 B]      
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Sources [4,802 B]     
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Sources [690 B]    
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main i386 Packages               
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/main i386 Packages [67.9 kB]  
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe i386 Packages [19.2 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse i386 Packages [1,403 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en              
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources/DiffIndex                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en          
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/universe i386 Packages [18.0 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/main i386 Packages [29.9 kB]  
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages [14 B]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/main Translation-en              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/multiverse Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/restricted Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/universe Translation-en          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse i386 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main i386 Packages              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted i386 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe i386 Packages          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main Translation-en             
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en_US           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Translation-en         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources                              
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Sources                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Sources                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Sources                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse i386 Packages
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Sources [37.0 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Sources [14 B]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Sources [49.8 kB]     
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex               
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Sources [690 B]     
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main i386 Packages [93.5 kB]   
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe i386 Packages [94.2 kB]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [1,403 B]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Translation-en_US
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_US
  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-11 - System error)
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en
  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-11 - System error)
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources
  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-11 - System error)
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages
  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-11 - System error)
Fetched 568 kB in 8min 0s (1,181 B/s) 
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-11 - System error)

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-11 - System error)

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-11 - System error)

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'dl.google.com:http' (-11 - System error)

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-11 - System error)

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-11 - System error)

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/source/Sources  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-11 - System error)

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-11 - System error)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: I think this is some temporary problem on the dns server. If you want you can meddle with the file `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: The root issue is DNS. Check for useful response (or error codes) when you run: **`dig archive.ubuntu.com`**

Comment: Could you post your `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Answer (score 4):

Close all programs/windows which have to do with installing software e.g. Synaptic, software-centre and terminals.

Now you should delete the locked files:

> You can delete the lock file with
>
> ```
> sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
> ```
>
> you may also need to delete the lock file in the cache directory
>
> ```
> sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
> ```
>
> by: [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/207874/44518)

and now you should open a terminal and run:

```
 sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

and now you can install everything you want again.

[Solution referred from](https://askubuntu.com/a/207874/44518)

Comment: Still not working!I already looked at that answer and tried that and also i tried again,but no luck

Comment: The problem on mine and the source you given is not the same. mine is   Something wicked happened resolving '' (-11 - System error)
and the source is Something wicked happened resolving '' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It could be the case that you are connecting to the Internet via a proxy so you should set up the proxies for `apt-get` by doing the following:

- create a folder in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`

  ```
  $ sudo leafpad /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/95proxies
  ```
- In side the opened file paste the following:

  ```
  Acquire::http::proxy "http://yourProxyIP:8080/";
  Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://yourProxyIP:8080/";
  Acquire::https::proxy "https://yourProxyIP:8080/";
  ```

Make sure to change yourProxyIP with a correct proxy IP.

Save the file by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update.
```

see: [How do I set systemwide proxy servers in Xubuntu, Lubuntu or Ubuntu Studio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150210/how-do-i-set-systemwide-proxy-servers-in-xubuntu-lubuntu-or-ubuntu-studio)

Comment: Thanks that solved my issue - admin had re-configured network with result my network requests went via proxy.

Answer (score 0):

type `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing`

Answer (score 0):

sudo resets environment by default (cf. man sudoers),
so if you add your proxy settings in .bashrc,
you may wanna move that to /etc/environment,
or fix the /etc/sudoers.d/ appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a proxy, then this link has some answers.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto

Look at the **Setting up apt-get to use a http-proxy** section within the web page.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]. Please elaborate in the procedure to answer this question. Please, don't provide just a link to the question. See [answer] for more information.